# Highcharts: How to remove the color under the data line in the Navigator

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the Highchart in the navigator there is a light color under the line. It gives an effect of area chart. It is possible to remove this color so that only a line is shown in Highchart navigator.

I am talking about this light bluish color under the line: 
[image]

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        navigator: {
            maskFill: 'rgba(180, 198, 220, 0.75)'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [out](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        navigator: {
            maskFill: 'rgba(180, 198, 220, 0.75)',
            series: {
                color: '#4572A7',
                fillOpacity: 0.00,
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```